# Does salat mean prayer to Allah?

Tags: salat, arabic, terminology, blessings-of-allah

Salam,
      I am confused about salat/namaz. Does salat mean prayer to Allah? But how come God sends salat to the prophet? If you know Arabic enough could you please explain salat in Quranic context? Thank you. God bless.

Answer (score 1):

Salat as term was mentioned in 100 different verses in the Quran. 85 of which were nouns, and 15 as verbs. The word originally has to meanings:

## A - To worship/supplicate/praise

---

1. Prayer(the worshipping).

> وَأَقِيمُوا الصَّلَاةَ وَآتُوا الزَّكَاةَ وَارْكَعُوا مَعَ
>   الرَّاكِعِينَ -
>
> 2:43
>   And establish prayer and give zakah and bow with those who bow [in
>   worship and obedience].

2. Supplication (Istigfar/ begging forgiveness)

> خُذْ مِنْ أَمْوَالِهِمْ صَدَقَةً تُطَهِّرُهُمْ وَتُزَكِّيهِم بِهَا
>   وَصَلِّ عَلَيْهِمْ ۖ إِنَّ صَلَاتَكَ سَكَنٌ لَّهُمْ ۗ وَاللَّهُ
>   سَمِيعٌ عَلِيمٌ - 9:103
>   Take, [O, Muhammad], from their wealth a charity by which you purify
>   them and cause them increase, and invoke [ Allah 's blessings] upon
>   them. Indeed, your invocations are reassurance for them. And Allah is
>   Hearing and Knowing.

3. To Read Quran

> قُلِ ادْعُوا اللَّهَ أَوِ ادْعُوا الرَّحْمَٰنَ ۖ أَيًّا مَّا تَدْعُوا
>   فَلَهُ الْأَسْمَاءُ الْحُسْنَىٰ ۚ وَلَا تَجْهَرْ بِصَلَاتِكَ وَلَا
>   تُخَافِتْ بِهَا وَابْتَغِ بَيْنَ ذَٰلِكَ سَبِيلًا - 17:110
>   Say, "Call upon Allah or call upon the Most Merciful. Whichever [name]
>   you call - to Him belong the best names." And do not recite [too]
>   loudly in your prayer or [too] quietly but seek between that an
>   [intermediate] way.

4. To Praise and bless (Thanaa')

> هُوَ الَّذِي **يُصَلِّي** عَلَيْكُمْ وَمَلَائِكَتُهُ لِيُخْرِجَكُم مِّنَ
>   الظُّلُمَاتِ إِلَى النُّورِ ۚ وَكَانَ بِالْمُؤْمِنِينَ رَحِيمًا -
>   33:43
>
> It is He who **confers blessing upon you**, and His angels [ask Him
>   to do so] that He may bring you out from darknesses into the light.
>   And ever is He, to the believers, Merciful.

Also

> إِنَّ اللَّهَ وَمَلَائِكَتَهُ **يُصَلُّونَ** عَلَى النَّبِيِّ ۚ يَا
>   أَيُّهَا الَّذِينَ آمَنُوا صَلُّوا عَلَيْهِ وَسَلِّمُوا تَسْلِيمًا -
>   33:56
>
> Indeed, Allah confers **blessing upon** the Prophet, and His angels [ask
>   Him to do so]. O you who have believed, ask [ Allah to confer]
>   blessing upon him and ask [ Allah to grant him] peace.

Comment: Option B is wrong as it is not about salat the prayer at all, there's a huge difference between  صلى and صلّى in Arabic.

Comment: So if I read the Quran and do good deeds is my salat complete? Or must I need to do traditional salat/namaz? If I pray 5 times a day what the advantages God will get so that if I do not do so, God will burn me hell-fire forever?

Comment: @Medi1Saif S-A-L-A has to meanings as per derivation from the root. Think about the word DARABA = Can have many meanings, to give example, to hit, to split.. etc

Comment: @AmuSultan the question was about how does Allah make salat. Salat you do is the worshipping. Allah sends His blessings and mercy unto believers. If you pray or not, Allah won't get any advantage. He needs nothing from us.

Comment: Medi1Saif@ That is why may I say praying like a robot is wasting time? We bow down and prostrate many times in a day. Is not it meaningless? Instead focusing on doing good deeds for me and humanity in the name of Allah. That is more meaningful.

Comment: @III-AK-III  تعريف و معنى صلى في معجم المعاني الجامع  https://www.almaany.com/ar/dict/ar-ar/%D8%B5%D9%84%D9%89/ . gives you details on the word. you can see Sala.  يَصْلَى be burned ; be burnt ; Burn Check this link that describes the meaning to the word in option B as well. https://www.almaany.com/quran/88/4/1/

Comment: The links provided show how the word derivative might have many meanings. @III-AK-III I see your point in sticking to the worshipping meaning only tho. I will delete option B to resolve confusion. thank you.

Comment: VendettaTurkey@ so God also sends salat to us, right? God also sent salat to the prophet, right? so we are bowing down and prostrating and sending salat to God? That is the wide understood meaning here about our salat to God?

Comment: The word daraba is a bad example it has one single meaning which put in relation with the context gives different meanings Arabic is a figurative language when you say: ضرب في الأرض this refers to Building up a tent while traveling therefore you may need to "hit" the tent peg in the soil etc. this way you may find a figurative explanation related to hitting for each apparently different meaning of ضرب.

Comment: Daraba has more than 25 meanings in Arabic. Not one single meaning!! How can you be so sure it’s only one meaning :) I think its a perfect example of how a word can vary in meaning in Quran.

Comment: Agree with @VendettaTurkey re multiple meanings for daraba. How do you figuratively explain “darab Allahu mathalan” where the whole expression means “give and example.” Where is the hitting here? The emphasis of the root is not on “hit” but rather more like make a distinction. I suppose “hit” makes a distinct “point.” Hence the way regarding wife-beating actually means “separation” not for the husband to “hit” his wife - rather to separate from her for a period of time. As for salat I’ll try to answer.